# SmoothStreamingMediaElement (.m3u8 ) in Windows phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, live-streaming

I want my application to play **(.m3u8)**  Live Streaming , i found this example 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SmoothStreaming/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3867

It works with other links but if i try my .m3u8 link it does not work.
Is there a specific way to play that type of streaming in windows phone?

```
     public MainPage()
{

        InitializeComponent();
        SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        phoneApplicationPage.ManipulationStarted += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(phoneApplicationPage_ManipulationStarted);
        phoneApplicationPage.ManipulationCompleted += new EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(phoneApplicationPage_ManipulationCompleted);
        seekbar.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(seekbar_MouseLeftButtonUp);

        List<Content> Contents = new List<Content>();
        Contents.Add(new Content("Media One", new Uri("http://fl1.viastreaming.net/iqraatv2/livestream/playlist.m3u8")));
        Contents.Add(new Content("Media Two", new Uri("http://Media_Two.ism/manifest")));
    Contents.Add(new Content("Media Three", new Uri("http://Media_Three.ism/manifest")));
        Contents.Add(new Content("Media Four", new Uri("http://Media_Four.ism/manifest")));

        comboBoxUrls.ItemsSource = Contents;
        comboBoxUrls.SelectedIndex = 0;
        comboBoxUrls.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBoxUrls_SelectionChanged);
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005883/playing-hls-m3u8-playlist-on-windows-phone-8-1/27026663#27026663

Answer (score 0):

It is possible take a look at this project from CodePlex it is working with HLS (m3u8) for both Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8!

[Windows Phone Streaming Media](http://phonesm.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly. [Playing HLS (m3u8 playlist) on Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005883/playing-hls-m3u8-playlist-on-windows-phone-8-1/27026663#27026663)
Download the player framework, consume the following DLL's:

[image: DLL's to consume]

Add the player to your xaml:

```
xmlns:mmppf="using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework"
xmlns:smmedia="using:SM.Media.MediaPlayer"



<mmppf:MediaPlayer IsFullScreenVisible="True" IsFullScreenEnabled="True" IsFullScreen="False"  CurrentStateChanged="mPlayer_CurrentStateChanged" x:Name="mPlayer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsFastForwardEnabled="False" IsInfoEnabled="False" IsLive="True" IsMoreEnabled="False" IsRewindEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsScrubbingEnabled="False" IsSeekEnabled="False" IsSkipBackEnabled="False" IsSkipAheadEnabled="False" IsReplayEnabled="False" IsTimelineVisible="False" IsTimeElapsedVisible="False" IsTimeRemainingVisible="False" RequestedTheme="Dark">
        <mmppf:MediaPlayer.Plugins>
            <smmedia:StreamingMediaPlugin />
        </mmppf:MediaPlayer.Plugins>

    </mmppf:MediaPlayer>
```

Then set your stream VIA code - or XAML if the URL never changes.