# Is it possible to stream live video (m3u8 link) on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, video, streaming, video-streaming

The question says it all.

I need my app to stream live video coming from a server in m3u8 format - AFAIK m3u8 is a playlist file

1. According to the following links I can use SMF player framework - but I am not able to get it to work

[SmoothStreamingMediaElement (.m3u8 ) in Windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584770/smoothstreamingmediaelement-m3u8-in-windows-phone)

http://phonesm.codeplex.com/

2. This link says Windows Phone doesnt support m3u8

[How to streams video file from m3u8 file in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072362/how-to-streams-video-file-from-m3u8-file-in-windows-phone-7)

Ive also heard that I need to open the m3u8 link with the phone's default video app - is it possible??   if so, how???